# Generate a dictionary with two-level keys from list

Tags: python, json, dictionary, data-structures, nested

Struggling to get the desired data structure.
(Note - pandas implementation are preferred)

Currently I have the following lists of dictionaries:

```
list1 =[
{'ip': '11.22.33.44', 'timestamp': 1665480231699, 'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198},
{'ip': '11.22.33.42', 'timestamp': 1665480231698, 'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198}, 
{'ip': '11.22.33.44', 'timestamp': 1665480231698, 'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198}
]
```

```
whitelist_metadata = [
  {
    'LogLevel': 'WARNING',
    'SpecificVersion': 'None',
    'TimeInterval(Min)': 1,
    'MetricMsg': 'DDR: XXXX count got lost',
    'AllowedOccurrenceInTimeInterval': 0   --> this means that we are allowing this msg always 
  },
  {
    'LogLevel': 'WARNING',
    'SpecificVersion': 'None',
    'TimeInterval(Min)': 1,
    'MetricMsg': 'Idle time larger than XXX time. retry: \\d ',
    'AllowedOccurrenceInTimeInterval': 5  --> this means that are allowing this msg only if happened not more than 5 times within 1min.
  }
]
```

And my desired output is

```
{
  '11.22.33.42': {
    1665480231698: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}']
  },
  '11.22.33.44': {
    1665480231698: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}'],
    1665480231699: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}']
  }
}
```

How do I achieve that?

---

**Attempts:**
Tried to play with pandas pivot to convert the data structure, but failed - this is what i tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
s = df.pivot(['ip', 'timestamp'], 'message')   
ss = s.assign(r=s.to_dict('records'))['r'].unstack(0).to_dict()
```

Here i already have issue with hows data looks like (the message part - i need it to be the timestamp value and not another key that appear as tupple)

```
>> print(S) 
                            ingestionTime                                                                                                  
message                     {"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"} {"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}
ip timestamp                                                                                                                    
11.22.33.42   1665480231698           NaN                                            1.665480e+12                                          
11.22.33.44   1665480231698  1.665480e+12                                                     NaN                                          
              1665480231699  1.665480e+12                                                     NaN
```

```
>> print(ss)
{
  '11.22.33.42': {
    1665480231698: {
      (
      'ingestionTime',
      '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}'
      ): nan,
      (
      'ingestionTime',
      '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}'
      ): 1665480263198.0
    },
    1665480231699: nan
  },
  '11.22.33.44': {
    1665480231698: {
      (
      'ingestionTime',
      '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}'
      ): 1665480263198.0,
      (
      'ingestionTime',
      '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}'
      ): nan
    },
    1665480231699: {
      (
      'ingestionTime',
      '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}'
      ): 1665480263198.0,
      (
      'ingestionTime',
      '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}'
      ): nan
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the desired output is

```
{
  '11.22.33.42': {
    1665480231698: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}']
  },
  '11.22.33.44': {
    1665480231698: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}'],
    1665480231699: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}']
  }
}
```

Considering the data that OP shared in the question, one doesn't actually need the second list. The `list1` would be enough.

The following function will do the work (the comments make it self-explanatory)

```
def todict(list1):

    dict1 = {} # create an empty dictionary

    for item in list1: # iterate over the list

        if item['ip'] not in dict1: # if the ip is not in the dictionary
            dict1[item['ip']] = {} # create a new key with the ip as value

        if item['timestamp'] not in dict1[item['ip']]: # if the timestamp is not in the dictionary
            dict1[item['ip']][item['timestamp']] = [] # create a new key with the timestamp as value

        dict1[item['ip']][item['timestamp']].append(item['message']) # append the message to the list

    return dict1
```

Then one gets the following

```
dict = todict(list1)

[Out]:

{'11.22.33.42': {1665480231698: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. '
                                 'retry:5"}']},
 '11.22.33.44': {1665480231698: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. '
                                 'retry:0"}'],
                 1665480231699: ['{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. '
                                 'retry:0"}']}}
```